# Добавление соответствующие аннотации типов для определённый функции. Включая аннотации для всех аргументов и типа возвращаемого значения

Tags: javascript, typescript

Мне дона задача - "В редакторе кода есть еще одна функция, использующая остальные параметры. Функция addPower(p, ...numsToAdd),, складывает pth степеней всех последующих аргументов. Таким образом, вызов addPower(2, 3, 4)возвращает 25, поскольку 3 в квадрате плюс 4 в квадрате равно 25. (Здесь мы используем оператор возведения в степень **.)

Добавьте соответствующие аннотации типов для этой функции. Включите аннотации для всех аргументов и типа возвращаемого значения."

```
function addPower(p, ...numsToAdd){
  let answer = 0; 
  for(let i = 0; i < numsToAdd.length; i++){
    answer += numsToAdd[i] ** p;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Я сделал таким образом.

```
function addPower(p: number[], ...numsToAdd: number[]){
    let answer = 0; 
    for(let i = 0; i < numsToAdd.length; i++){
      answer += numsToAdd[i] ** p;
    }
    return answer;
  }
```

Выводит вот такую ошику.

```
index.ts:38:33 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

38       answer += numsToAdd[i] ** p;
                                   ~


Found 1 error.
```

Правильно - ли я всё делаю?
Объясните мне!

Comment: `p` объявлен как `number[]`. <spoiler>а должен быть `number`</spoiler>. а ещё вы не прописали тип возвращаемого значения

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в том, что в первый аргумент не массив, а число.

*Как верно подметил [@nörbörnën](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2659/n%c3%b6rb%c3%b6rn%c3%abn)*.

```js
function addPower(p: number, ...numsToAdd: number[]){
  let answer = 0; 

  for(let i = 0; i < numsToAdd.length; i++){
    answer += numsToAdd[i] ** p;
  }

  return answer;
}


console.log(addPower(2, 2, 2));
```

[Песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoApwO4FMBOAFAA4BciYIAtgEYEA0iAdC5VQM4AqcAguuWzr4A2gF0AlAG8AUIkQAbXFBRh2efIgC8iAAwBuRNNmJgcIouUwtug1YA8Fal17omisAHMoAC1sBqPyljOWRVdUQ-bTZnPlRhGFFEACokxGI9YwBfIzl8JRB8JFC1AgzsowgEdjhFNzgPQjRMHAJCACZGDsQ28XE9IA)